# Sticky headings in 1 column

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Can I create sticky headings on scroll in 1 column without them overlapping? Below is what I have so far but when I scroll down the h1s just overlap.

**Update: I want the headings to stack as I scroll not for the subsequent headings to push it off screen.**

```css
.column {
  overflow: visible;
}

h1 {
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-12 col-md-4 column">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no overlap in the demo above. Most of your CSS isn't actually doing anything, btw.

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap has classes for [overflow](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/overflow/#overflow) and [position](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/position/). You should get to know the library a bit better. Duplicating rules is inefficient. If you do create custom classes, make their names semantic. "Column" for a class which sets position is unintuitive.

Comment: FYI also, most documents [shouldn't have more than one level 1 heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#avoid_using_multiple_h1_elements_on_one_page).

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping? Your demo does not illustrate the problem.

Comment: My best guess is that you want the previous heading to be pushed off-screen by the subsequent heading rather than the headings ending up stacked. But I shouldn't have to guess. Please update your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Update provided @Moob.

Comment: @EJ740 your update does not really clarify anything. To my mind, they currently are stacked. When at the top each heading overlaps the prior one and is thus 'stacked' on top. Perhaps an image of what you have vs what you want would help.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the `h1` in some element, something like this:

```css
.column {
  overflow: visible;
}
div {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
h1 { 
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>Heading 1</h1></div>
<div><h1>Heading 2</h1></div>
<div><h1>Heading 3</h1></div>
<div><h1>Heading 3</h1></div>
```